# Filter Duplicates by count of a character Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, data-validation

I have a data list of around 32000 items in column A. Each of these items has many duplicates, some having 1 duplicate, up to about 5 or so max. Each cell has multiple sku's, divided by a /.

What I need to do is determine the count of /'s in a single cell, and if that count equals the amount of duplicates, color the cell green, if not, color the cell orange.

Example:

```
1001/1002/1003
1001/1002/1003
1001/1002/1003
```

All 3 of these cells would turn green, there are 2 slashes, and 2 duplicates of each cell (or 3 total cells duplicated)

```
1001/1002/1003
1001/1002/1003
```

Both of these would turn orange, as there are 2 slashes, and 3 entries. They would also be orange if there were 4 entries, or any number other than 3.

I can use formulas as necessary, and can even do this in multiple steps, such as an extra calculation cell that outputs yes or no, and I can color them myself by filtering etc.

I prefer to avoid VB in this as it is used by many users that have absolutely no clue how to use excel, but if necessary, I can use VB.

Comment: @pnuts the 3 are green as there are 2 /'s for 3 entries, meaning a total of 3 part numbers, and 3 entries.  The bottom example is orange as there are 3 part numbers, and 2 entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this can be done using Conditional Formatting. As the two colors are exact opposites, you can either color all the cells 1 colors and detect (and change color) for other condition, or you can use 2 conditional format rules.

Anyway, formula to detect which cells should be colored green. Assumes that data is in col A and the active cell is A2.

`=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","")))+1`

and if you need the opposite to detect for orange:

`=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)<>(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","")))+1`

Comment: im not entirely sure I understand how this works - I need to compare the amount of duplicates to the amount of /'s in the item. There may be both more or less items divided by slashes as there are entries. From what I can tell, this formula does nothing to determine how many duplicates there are.

Comment: marking yours as correct as after further review, its basically the exact same as what I ended up using :), just in reverse!

Comment: You may have figured this out, but basically the problem is to figure out how many "/" are in the cell. If we take the length of text - the length of text after we remove the "/", we can know how many there were. I add 1 since we want item count, not slash count. Then we compare that with the COUNTIF result to figure out if there's a match.

Answer (score 0):

The formula I ended up using was

```
=IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))+1=COUNTIF($A:$A,A2),"OK","BAD")
```

Placed into Cell B2 - then filled down - I then filtered column B by OK or BAD, and just manually colored the bulk column A.